# HP ALM query by name with spaces

Tags: hp-quality-center, alm

I am trying to use HP ALM 11's REST API. So far I have been able to query stuff fine. Now I have hit a case where the name of the entity (a test folder) is with spaces: "WebView - New Thin UI"

```
{name['WebView - New Thin UI']}
```

If I specify the query like `{name['WebView*']}` it returns a bunch of test folders among which is also the one mentioned above.

However, if I use the full name including the spaces (The string gets escaped and spaces converted to `+`. I can see `GET /qcbin/rest/domains/XXX/projects/XXX/test-folders?query=%7Bname%5B%27WebView+-+New+Thin+UI%27%5D%7D&page-size=max&start-index=1 HTTP/1.1` in the logs) I get no results (empty set, not an error).

I do not see how else I should specify the query criterion so that it would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double quotes instead of single quotes.

Following query works fine with my instance and returns single record.

http://hp.gaurav.com:8080/qcbin/rest/domains/DEFAULT/projects/TestProject/defects?query={name[="Sample query test"]}

Comment: Is the `=` before the `"Sample query test"` necessary? I think that might be what I am missing. I have already tried double quotes. I will try this later today.